# Casting Interface property in Derived Class

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I was wondering if there was a way to cast a interface property in a derived class, for example:

```
public interface IImageGenerator
{
    object FinalImage { get; set; }
}

public MyClass : IImageGenerator
{
    public Image FinalImage{ get;set; }  // Its cast as Image instead of Object
}
```

If things are setup in the interface as objects I have to do `FinalImage as Image` all over the place and was wondering if there was a way to not do that.  The only other thing I can think is to create a property in the derived class that returns the interface property as a Image representation e.g.

```
public Image MyCastProperty
{
    get {return FinalImage as Image;}
}
```

Comment: What other types can `FinalImage` be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this:

```
public interface IImageGenerator
{
    object FinalImage { get; set; }
}

public MyClass : IImageGenerator
{
    public Image FinalImage{get;set;}

    object IImageGenerator.FinalImage
    {
        get { return FinalImage; }
        set
        {
            if (!(value is Image))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Must be an image");
            }
            FinalImage = (Image) value;
        }
    }
}
```

Alternative - and preferably - make the interface generic:

```
public interface IImageGenerator<T>
{
    T FinalImage { get; set; }
}
```

Do you really need `IImageGenerator` to have a *setter* in the property though? That doesn't sound like something I'd expect for a *generator*.

Comment: Generics are definitely the way to go with these sorts of things.